# How to place topology so there is no crease?

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface, topology, artifacts

I've been stuck on this corner for ages. I want to make it a sharp corner and the edge that's connecting it to be sharp as well . I've tried hard modelling tutorials but none of them fixed my problem. I've tried subdividing but that just makes every every on my model creased? Thanks for any help!

[image: always a crease in the corner that I can't get rid of]

[image: tried many placements, this is the closest I can get to no crease]

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

You have giant n-gons all over for no discernible reason. Figure those out, either git rid of them or connect them to something else and that will probably help. N-Gons aren't the worst thing in the world but that should be first on your mind if you're having issues with sub-d distortion.

[image]

You should also try to even things out in that corner. The main thing that can cause Sub-D distortion is when the subdivision tries to interpolate between bunched up and evenly spaced geometry, right next to eachother.

Something more like this:

[image]

Also make sure these faces are relatively planar. Having a few verts sticking out weirdly will ruin a Sub-D surface.

You can do this relatively easily by using *Select Linked Flat Faces* and then scaling to 0 on whatever axis you need.

[image]

If you need to flatten out wonky verts on a curved surface, you can do this by modelling a simplified version of the curved surface you want to attain.

**"Helmet" and "Simplified Surface":**

[image]

Then select all the vertices you want to correct and add them to a vertex group.

[image]

Then give the helmet a shrinkwrap modifier and set the target as the curve object. You will probably need to adjust the offset and maybe add or remove some verts from the group to get it just right.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! My faces form the front of a helmet. Is there any way to make sure the vertices don't stick out weirdly on a curved surface?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you.